# Suitable data delimiter to separator jpeg, m4a and text(utf8) in one file

Tags: ios

I want to combine three different kind of data: jpeg, m4a, and utf8 text in one data file. Could anyone recommend any suitable data delimiter?

Particularly, I'm working on iOS.

Comment: Use a zipfile.  I bet you there are stock libraries for that on iOS.

Comment: @Zack, good point! Let me try.

Comment: @Zack, I'm still confused. How to distinguish different file?

Comment: that depends on the zip library you are using. i'm using objective-zip and have there a calls like [zipFile gotoFirstFileInZip], [zipFile readCurrentFileInZip], and so on ...